# How many calories are burnt while typing on the keyboard?

Tags: weight-loss, calories

**I apologize if this is not the correct place for this question. If it isn't,  feel free to move it!**

---

There have been several studies on the amount of calories burnt by clicking a mouse. For instance, *Convert Anything to Calories (PHP Science World)* has made the following calculation:

*“On average, 16.7 micromoles of ATP (Adenosine triphosphate) are consumed in moving one gram of muscle for one second. So, the total amount of ATP burned to move 11.7 grams of muscle in the index finger is approximately 195 micromoles (11.7g×16.7μ mol/g). There are 7.3 calories in one mole of ATP energy, so the number of calories burned in clicking the mouse equals about 1.42 {(7.3/1000) X 195)}.”*

Note that *calories* here does not refer to the commonly named "calories", which in fact are kilocalories.

Are there any similar studies on the amount of calories burnt *while typing*? Or perhaps more specifically in the form **calories/keypress**?

Comment: I know of no relevant studies; however, I suspect the answer to your title question (that is, "How many calories are burnt while typing on the keyboard?") is "highly variable and also negligible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Harvard Health Publications, typing on a computer burns 41 calories per half hour for a 125-pound person. A 155-pound person burns 51 calories typing for 30 minutes and a 185-pound person burns 61 calories doing the same job.